# Binding model to view issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have my own model classes, which are public, but when making a view, I cannot find the model itself in the list of models to bind to. Why is this? Can I bind the model to the view somehow afterwards?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to the top of your `View`:

`@model your.namespace.YourModelClass`

Then your `controller`s' `action method` needs to return an appropriate instance of `YourModelClass`:

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    return View(new YourModelClass());
}
```